# Outlook + Office365 & VLAN issues

Tags: vlan, microsoft-office-365

I am having major issues with Outlook and Office365. Mail is sitting in my outbox and not sending. This only started to happen after I had implemented a VLAN infrastructure at my office.

I have setup multiple VLAN's in my office. My servers and workstations are on one VLAN and other VLAN's for other server hosting purposes, such as backups and voice.

HP1820 - SW 1 is connected to SW 2 via VLAN trunk

HP1820 - SW 2 has a connection from SW 1 and has the extra VLAN trunk to the Draytek 2952

HP1820 PoE - SW3 directly connected via VLAN trunk to the Draytek 2952

I have 3 HP 1820 switches and 1 of them is a PoE (SW3). The PoE's sole purpose is for VoiP and is directly connected to my Draytek 2952 via tagged port on the switch. All is working fine.

The other 2 HP 1820's are for the main network and i have around 5 VLAN's setup. SW1 and SW2 are connected via Port #24 via a VLAN Trunk.

On SW2 port #23 is connected to the Draytek via VLAN trunk also.

All VLAN connections have internet and able to communicate internally as well out.

I have one major big issue with Outlook. My mail is stuck and i have captured some Wireshark TCP captures.

Can someone please help me as i am baffled and confused as to why this is happening only with the connection to Office365.

Thanks

[Wireshark Capture #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQInB.jpg)

[Wireshark Capture #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH4Lw.jpg)

Comment: I have solved the puzzle. MTU is the factor.

Comment: After hours of troubleshooting and I decided to read the whole entire manual of the switch i have uncovered that VLAN tags add an extra 22 bytes on top of the MTU size and therefore packet loss was the issue. I reduced my MTU to 1450 on my NIC and voila Office sends email with no issues